# Need to decrypt KeePass database on Linux

Tags: linux, encryption

I was finally getting to switching my new laptop from Windows 8 over to Linux. I had only one important file on that I needed to keep, and that was my dogecoin wallet file.

It had a really weird password I didn't even know that was generated by KeePass. My KeePass database in on Microsofts cloud server thing for storage. I know the databases password, but I don't know how I will be able to use it from Linux.

This is SUPER IMPORTANT because if I don't have that password back, all of my coins will be lost forever.

Essentially, what I need to be able to do is view everything in the KeePass database from Linux, even though KeePass is only available for Windows. How will I go about doing this?

Comment: Question needs less panic and more [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=run+windows+program+on+linux) – there are a few ways to run "only available for Windows" programs on non-Windows.

Answer (score 3):

KeePass *is* available on Linux:

- version 2.x runs under Mono;
- version 1.x runs under Wine;
- version 1.x also has an open-source "KeePassX" alternative that runs on Linux natively.

I'm not sure which version of Linux you are using but you can find the instructions for each distro at the following link: http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#mono